# My content leaves my screen, how can I prevent this?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am making a full-screen c# application, with WPF.
But my content is leaving my screen because i want the height and width of the application to be dynamic.
This is my current test:

```
<Window x:Class="examen.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:examen"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="#024886"
    Title="MainWindow" WindowStyle="None" WindowState="Maximized" >
    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FBB510" Height="84" RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20" Stroke="Black"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom" MouseLeftButtonDown="Rectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown"
            Canvas.Left="248" Width="89" Canvas.Top="242"/>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

How can I make sure the content will stay at its place?

Comment: Can you describe what happens and what you want to happens? Is content too big and you want to: 1) scroll it 2) scale it (zoom?) 3) something else?

Comment: i guess its zoomed in

Comment: You can try wrapping your canvas in a viewbox. This will scale everything. So you can set a static width of the canvas and the viewbox will resize it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution...

Suround all of your windows controls with a ViewBox....

```
    <Viewbox>

        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Fill="#FBB510" Height="84" RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" MouseLeftButtonDown="Rectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown" Canvas.Left="248" Width="89" Canvas.Top="242"/>
         </Canvas>

    </Viewbox>
```